# resistance of wires

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrical-resistance, home-experiment

i have an upcoming open investigation at my school on wire resistance, in preparation for it i want to find out if duct tape would effect the multimeter's readings. i need to connect wire to a multimeter for investigating wire resistance, and the cheapest option instead of buying fancy clamps is to tape it. i personally doubt it would affect the readings but not to sure if the tapes have materials that affect it.

Comment: You can save a little money, but you will incur a lot of headache. Alligator clips are dirt cheap these days. I can get useful ones for less than 50 cents a lead.

Comment: ive actually never cam across doing this test before does any of you guys have a link for a good procedure?

Comment: One would typically do something like this: http://www.bsieducation.org/Education/14-19/applied-science/standard-procedure/sp-0010.shtml. Get yourself a wooden board with two isolating pegs in it at a distance of 0.5-1m. String the wire up tight enough that you can easily connect to it without the contacts slipping. You need two meters, one to measure the current trough the wire and one for the voltage. Do a four-point measurement, i.e. you use two clips to supply current trough the wire at its ends and you use two different ones to measure voltage at two point between the two current clips.

Answer (score 0):

Duct tape should be okay. A few small alligator clips from the hardware store would be better.

I assume you're going to twist the wire around a solid thin probe.  That connection point will introduce uncertainty in your result because of the uncertainty in length and contact resistance. The contact resistance will depend on the surface area contact which will depend (non-linearly) on the contact pressure. Duct tape won't provide the best pressure.

Comment: ill save up for some alligator clips, i think my school provides them, ill ask my teacher when i can